# Getting segmentation fault in my trie implementation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wrote a C++ program for `trie` implementation. But it displays segmentation fault after getting the input `string` (here named as `elem`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct trie {
    char val;
    vector<struct trie*> children;

    trie(char c){ 
        val = c; 
    }

    struct trie* add(char c){ 
        struct trie* node = new struct trie(c);
        children.push_back(node);
        return node;
    }

    struct trie* find(char c){
        for (auto child: children)
            if(child->val == c) return child;
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int present(struct trie* root, string& elem, int pos) {
    if(pos == elem.size()) return 1;
    root = root->find(elem[pos]);
    if(root == nullptr) return 0;
    return present(root, elem, ++pos);
}

int main() {
    int testcase;
    cin >> testcase;

    int elements;
    string elem;
    while(testcase--){
        cin >> elements;
        struct trie root('z');
        struct trie* temp;
        while(elements--){
            cin >> elem;
            temp = &root;
            for(auto c : elem){
                temp = temp->find(c);
                if(temp == nullptr)
                    temp = temp->add(c);
            }
        }
        cin >> elem;
        cout << present(&root, elem, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me with debugging this error ?

Comment: `if(temp == nullptr) temp = temp->add(c);` here you dereference `nullptr`

Comment: Can you suggest me any other way to implement this check ?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that the `segmentation fault` arises immediately after the statement `cin >> elem;` (I used out to check where it stops executing :[ )

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, you are right. I've never used a debugger. And sure, I'll try it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different struct trie pointer to assign the trie find method return value. Something like below (only giving the modified logic below)-

```
while (elements--) {
            cin >> elem;
            temp = &root;
            struct trie* exists;
            for (auto c : elem) {
                exists = temp->find(c);
                if (exists == nullptr)
                    temp = temp->add(c);
                else
                    temp = exists;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I do so, how can I use the returned pointer `exists` in the next iteration, as `temp` is still pointing to the previous node?

Comment: @San if the node exists then you do nothing. Only if it doesn't exist you add a new node which would update temp.

Comment: No, if the node exists, I return the node, else I add the node to` children` and then return the node.